# MSER text detection issue

Tags: python, opencv, mser

I try to use MSER algorithm to text detection. I use this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Create MSER object
mser = cv2.MSER_create()

#Your image path i-e receipt path
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

#Convert to gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

vis = img.copy()

#detect regions in gray scale image
regions, _ = mser.detectRegions(gray)

hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]

cv2.polylines(vis, hulls, 1, (0, 255, 0))

cv2.imshow('img', vis)

cv2.waitKey(0)

mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1), dtype=np.uint8)

for contour in hulls:

    cv2.drawContours(mask, [contour], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

#this is used to find only text regions, remaining are ignored
text_only = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow("text only", text_only)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But I get very interesting results. MSER can't detect all text on image.

Test image:
[image: Test image]

Result image:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to save pictures with text to png format. Or use jpeg with 100% quality

Comment: Hi! I use images in png format.

Comment: Ha! See yours code: img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

And your example in jpeg: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOSRE.jpg

Comment: I know, it is only for example, I have not access to png images now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV text module contains a couple of methods for text detection. For your example the simplest method is the ERFilterNM - [python example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.py).
See you on detection result for png screen:
[image: text detection result:]
Parameters:

```
er1 = cv.text.createERFilterNM1(erc1,6,0.00005f,0.08f,0.2f,true,0.1f)
er2 = cv.text.createERFilterNM2(erc1,0.15)
```